# Error No such file or directory when using selenium-wire and Pyinstaller

Tags: python, selenium

So, I am making this little program that requires selenium wire. I compiled it into an .exe file using Pyinstaller and when I tried to run it on another computer it threw me this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI66482\seleniumwire\ca.crt'
```

I am using Chrome driver and have its path as well as it's binary declared in my code and when I was doing the test I had the binary and the driver in the correct location. I tried using normal selenium, and it worked just fine.

Comment: you would need to take a look at the python program and how you are referring `seleniumwire\ca.crt` , try to put code generic vs hard coding. Please paste your python code and we can suggest further. Thanks

Comment: did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Bump-having the same issue